# Woocommerce pagination link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a custom page template and display the products by category here is my code:

```
/<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Drones
 */

// Set the parameters of your query
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_cat' => 'drones' );

// Override directly the query of the page, so that it is propagated to all the functions and doesn't break any WooCommerce feature
query_posts( $args );

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
```

So in the front end view the products are displayed and also the pagination link
here is the issue when i clicked unto the pagination the product displayed are still the same as the product in the first page and when i checked the link it looks like this

```
www.wordpress.com/drones/page/2
```

And when I tried to put product-category in the links it works:

```
www.wordpress.com/product-category/drones/page/2
```

How will fix this one? It seems that it needs a little tweak on the code. please help

Comment: Why you don't use Woocommerce shortcode like for example `[products columns="4" category="drones" paginate="true"]` or `[product_category columns="4" category="drones" paginate="true"]` with any other needed arguments. It's could be much more simpler and you will not get any pagination problems.

Comment: My client wants to be format like that.

Comment: Then, your not helping anyway.

Comment: Then if you don't have an answer why did you commented my thread? You know in yourself that you don't have an answer?